# nodejs shopify rest api pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I'm trying to get all products from Shopify store via rest API and with

```
direction=next&last_id=id
```

it does not return all products.

I see that there is a different way to paginate products endpoint with headers but I'm not pretty good with NodeJS and don't know how to strip strings that I receive to have only needed parameters.

Below is response example and I need only page_info from rel="next" element

```
<https://xxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json?limit=250&page_info=xxx>; rel="previous", <https://xxx.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/products.json?limit=250&page_info=xxx>; rel="next"
```

any ideas?

splitting to array and search by chars

Comment: You could accomplish this with a simple regex match. string.match(regex)

Comment: @Kwright02 i`m not really sure that it's possible since page_info are dynamic and changes on every page

Comment: That's the point of regex. It's meant for dynmaic use cases. Check out regexr.com